# Is it possible to toggle tabs in a browser window using C# and perform specific tasks on specific tabs?

Tags: c#, .net, automation

Web automation: I want to do it in multiple tabs(or different windows if tabs not possible); like identify which tab/window is what/active, and then perform some tasks like checkbox, link click, read value from the webpage, fill box, click button, etc, and then move on to the other webpage(tab/window).

I know how to click button, fill form, checkbox, but only on one page, I don't know how to toggle tabs/windows, identify which tab is what(if possible then mark which tab/window is what so that I don't have to identify them every time)

there is no browser specific preference

Comment: Maybe you can change your mind. Here's a great browser plugin automation tool that should help you out, check it out https://github.com/AutomaApp/automa

Comment: I WANT TO READ VALUES FROM THE WEBPAGE AND SOME FILES FROM MY PC AND THEN TAKE ACTION BASIS ON IT, NO PLUGIN CAN SUPPORT THAT; IF THERE IS THEN PLZ SHARE

Comment: This plugin is also supported, you can set the trigger to visit a certain website, so you can use C# to call the browser to open the page.